# How do I create a simple hamburger menu or menu navegation

Tags: xamarin

I have the following command but I am not able to call the menu navagation or simple hamburger menu, I have already the ready xaml I have my app.cs, how to call the menu in my main page

Note: my project is cross plataform (IOS, Android, WP)

```
 public class App : Application
{

public App()
{
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainTabbedPage() { Title = "Titulo Topo" });
}

public class MainTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainTabbedPage()
    { 
        Children.Add(new AboutPage_1() { Title = "Titulo 1" });
        Children.Add(new AboutPage_2() { Title = "Titulo 2" });
        Children.Add(new AboutPage_3() { Title = "Titulo 3" });
        Children.Add(new AboutPage_4() { Title = "Titulo 4" });
        Children.Add(new AboutPage_5() { Title = "Titulo 5" });
        Children.Add(new AboutPage_6() { Title = "Titulo 6" });
    }
}
```

---

MenuPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
x:Class="Hanselman.Portable.Views.MenuPage"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
Title="{Binding Title}"
Icon="{Binding Icon}">
 <ContentPage.Content>
   <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <ListView 
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            x:Name="ListViewMenu">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <BoxView Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                             Grid.RowSpan="4"
                             BackgroundColor="#234084"/>
                    <Label 
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Text="Titulo"
                        TextColor="White"
                        FontSize="30"
                        Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="12">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!--<Image Source="{Binding Icon}" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25"/>-->
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="18"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: use a Master Detail page: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/

Comment: With that comes another problem, how to put TabbedPage inside my masterpage?

Comment: You would typically make the DetailPage (not Master) a tabbed page.  What problem are you having with this?

Comment: Sorry, I gave it a main page, but really MasterDetailPage, I can not put tabbebpages inside the MasterDetailPage

Comment: you are saying "can not" without giving any detail about what specifically you've tried or what sorts of errors you're getting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662871/tabbed-page-inside-master-detail-page-xamarin

Comment: Do you have any examples via command? Without using xaml

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tabs = new TabbedPage();
tabs.Children.Add(new ContentPage { Title = "TabA" });
tabs.Children.Add(new ContentPage { Title = "TabB" });
tabs.Children.Add(new ContentPage { Title = "TabC" });

this.Master = new ContentPage { Title = "Master" };
this.Detail = tabs;
```

Comment: error: System.InvalidOperationException: Master and Detail must be set before adding MasterDetailPage to a container